# rich:tabPanel loads data of all tabs on tab switch

Tags: jsf-2, tabs, richfaces, tabpanel

I have a  in my ui file which has switchType set to ajax. It has 4 tabs. The problem is when I click on tab1 , it loads data of tab1. But, when I click on tab2, it loads data of tab1 and tab2. When tab3 is clicked, it loads data of tab1, tab2 and tab3. And so on. How can I avoid this behaviour? It should load the data of only the tab which is selected(or clicked on) and not all the tabs before it.

I use richfaces 4 and JSF 2.0

Below is the code :

```
<rich:tabPanel  status="loadingMask" id="tabPanelTest" switchType="ajax" style="height:80%;width:100%;padding-top:5px">
        <a4j:ajax event="itemchange"  render="tabPanelTest" />
        <rich:tab header="Tab 1" id="TAB 1">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="height:100%;width:100%;" id="tab1view">
                <ui:include src="tab-1-file.xhtml"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="Tab 2" id="TAB 2">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="height:100%;width:100%;" id="tab2view">
                <ui:include src="components/tab-2-file.xhtml"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="Tab 3" id="TAB 3">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="height:100%;width:100%;" id="tab3view">
                <ui:include src="tab-3-file.xhtml"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="Tab 4" id="TAB 4">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="height:100%;width:100%;" id="tab4view">
                <ui:include src="tab-4-file.xhtml"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </rich:tab>             
</rich:tabPanel>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "loads the data"? How do you know that ? (you should only see one panel). And have you tried it without the `<a4j:ajax>`? I think this is not needed and fact that you render the whole panel might cause this behaviour.

Comment: It is trying to render the previous tabs too. Thats what I meant when I said "loads data". It tries to access the getters of all the variables that are there in the previous tabs. When I put in debug mode, and click on tab3, I can see the controller and getter methods of the backing beans of tab1 and tab2 getting called.

Comment: This is the normal behaviour I think. JSF will run through the views component tree and will search for the tab. Obviously it will run through the first tabs first to find correct one. Try to work with a `rendered="#{...}"` and disable the non-active tabs like this so the content will not be accessed anymore.

Comment: Duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535634/rich-tabpanels-getters-invoked-when-tab-content-not-rendered